# Excel VBA Word mailmerge - Word object not closing immediately

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have an excel VBA project that performs a "Word" mailmerge.  I believe I am opening and closing the Word doc and app properly, but the "winword" process remains open for a good 45 seconds after my code is finished executing.

The result is that Excel continues to behave like it is executing the "Sub" until after the "winword" process finally disappears.  Then Excel is released and I can interact with it (in this case a user form).

I don't believe I had this behavior prior to the latest release of Office 365.

Here is the code I am using to invoke word, etc:

```
'Start a new document in Word
                Set oApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Set oDoc = oApp.Documents.Add
                Set oRange = oDoc.Range

                oDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdCatalog
                oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
                oDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=FullFilePath, LinkToSource:=True, _
                SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `namedRangeDynamic`"

                With oDoc.MailMerge

                    Set HdrRange = oDoc.Sections.Item(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                    oDoc.Tables.Add Range:=HdrRange, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=4

                    Set oTable = HdrRange.Tables(1)

                        With oTable
                            .Borders.Enable = True
                            .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(8), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                            .Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(4.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                            .Columns(3).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(3.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                            .Columns(4).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(6.75), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                            .Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -570408705
                            .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Account Name"
                            .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Last Name"
                            .Cell(1, 3).Range.Text = "First Name"
                            .Cell(1, 4).Range.Text = "Organization"
                        End With

                oDoc.Tables.Add oRange, 1, 4

                Set oTable = oRange.Tables(1)

                    With oTable
                        .Borders.Enable = True
                        .Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(8), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                        .Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(4.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                        .Columns(3).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(3.5), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                        .Columns(4).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=oApp.CentimetersToPoints(6.75), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
                    End With

                    With oTable
                        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Size = 8
                        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
                        .Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -570359809
                        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Size = 8
                        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
                        .Cell(1, 3).Range.Font.Size = 8
                        .Cell(1, 3).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
                        .Cell(1, 4).Range.Font.Size = 8
                        .Cell(1, 4).Range.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    End With

                    With .Fields
                        .Add oApp.Selection.Range, "Account_Name"
                        oApp.Selection.MoveRight
                        .Add oApp.Selection.Range, "Last_Name"
                        oApp.Selection.MoveRight
                        .Add oApp.Selection.Range, "First_Name"
                        oApp.Selection.MoveRight
                        .Add oApp.Selection.Range, "Company"
                    End With


                End With

                oDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                oDoc.MailMerge.Execute


           If cb2_selected = "PDF" Then

                oApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
                SaveAs_FilepathA & "\" & lb2_array_acctName & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
                OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
                wdExportAllDocument, FROM:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
                IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
                wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
                True, UseISO19005_1:=False

            Else

                oApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=SaveAs_FilepathA & "\" & lb2_array_acctName & ".docx", FileFormat:= _
                wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
                :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
                :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
                SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15

            End If


'Close Word
                oDoc.Close False
                oApp.Visible = False
                oApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False

                Set oDoc = Nothing

    'Prevent save to Normal template
                    oApp.NormalTemplate.Saved = True
                    oApp.Quit

                Set oApp = Nothing
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see that you set oApp = Nothing? That *might* help...

Comment: I actually do have that in the code as the last line, but didn't grab it when originally posting code (post revised).  The Word instance eventually closes, but only after about 45 seconds.

Comment: So, after some trial & error debugging, I eventually "Set" all objects I had invoked to "= Nothing".  This included the "oTable" and "HdrRange" and "oRange" objects.  It appears that unless these are cleared (ie: Set oRange = Nothing), some kind of connection lingers between Excel and Word that holds up Excel from moving on.  So it appears it had nothing to do with closing the instance of Word, but rather clearing any objects used in the merge so Excel could move on.

Comment: One would have to ask why you have all the code that does the basic document creation instead of simply using a template with all the required boilerplate content, including the mergefield *in-situ*? Your current process is quite inefficient, especially with its unnecessary use of Selection. Depending on the number of records to be merged, it could take Word some time to complete its processing after your 'oDoc.MailMerge.Execute' statement.

Comment: I fully agree that it is not the most efficient way to get the job done.  I did make the choice not to use a template in this case as I wanted it to be as self-contained as possible and not have to rely on pre-configured template files.  It is all a learning process though and my next version will likely be a little better.  Always looking for good resources.  :)